# How model multiple 1-to-n relationships in firebase?

Tags: firebase, data-modeling, modeling

I'm coming from Parse to Firebase and want to implement a project with non-trivial 1-to-n relationships as follows:

- Entity --1-to-n--> Person
- Person --1-to-n--> Credit
- Creditor --1-to-n--> Credit

**Data write and read** — added for clarification

Person and related Credit will be created at the same time.

Each Person may read / update each of its own Credit a few times.

Then it will be read by Creditor: I will run queries to gather all the Credit of any given Creditor.

[image: model diagram]

Looking at Firebase's documentation I would say that I would have to use the relationship below, but wonder if I'm thinking correctly.

```
{
  "entities": {
    "entityA": {
      "name": "...",
      "persons": {
        "personA": true,
        "personB": true,
        "...": true
      }
    },
    "entityB": {
      "name": "...",
      /* ... */
    }
  },
  "persons": {
    "personA": {
      "name": "...",
      "entity": "entityA",
      "credits": {
        "creditA0": true,
        "creditA1": true,
      }
    },
    "personB": {
      "name": "...",
      /* ... */
    }
  },
  "credits": {
    "creditA0": {
      "amount": "2000,00",
      /* ... */
      "institution": "institutionA"
    },
    "creditA1": {
      "amount": "5000,00",
      /* ... */,
      "institution": "institutionB"
    }
  },
  "institutions": {
    "institutionA": {
      "name": "...",
      "credits": {
        "creditA0": true
      }
    },
    "institutionB": {
      "name": "...",
      "credits": {
        "creditA1": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In NoSQL you often model your data for the way your application uses it. For this and more patterns, see this article on [NoSQL Data Modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/). This means that it will be impossible to say whether you've modeled "correctly", until you show the queries that you want to run.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Added details to clarify data writes and reads